# how to get proper labels in a scatter plot multiindex dataframe

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("dataset.xls", sep='\t',index_col=0)

Nr  TID PID x [pixel]   y [pixel]
1   1   1   266.659 243.028
2   1   2   266.659 243.028
3   1   3   266.659 242.372
4   1   4   266.659 242.372
5   1   5   266.659 242.372
6   1   6   267.972 238.433
7   1   7   267.972 238.433
8   1   8   267.972 237.777
9   2   1   267.315 235.808
10  2   2   267.315 234.495
11  2   3   267.315 234.495
12  2   4   267.972 232.526
13  2   5   267.972 232.526
14  2   6   267.972 231.213
15  2   7   267.972 231.213
16  3   1   267.315 230.556
17  3   2   267.315 230.556
18  3   3   267.972 227.931
19  3   4   267.972 227.931
20  3   5   267.972 227.931
21  3   6   267.972 227.931
22  3   7   267.972 225.962
```

Using pandas, I converted to a multiindex datrame where the index are TID and PID:

```
df = dataset.set_index(["TID", "PID"])

TID PID x [pixel]   y [pixel]
1   1   266.659 243.028
1   2   266.659 243.028
1   3   266.659 242.372
1   4   266.659 242.372
1   5   266.659 242.372
1   6   267.972 238.433
1   7   267.972 238.433
1   8   267.972 237.777
2   1   267.315 235.808
2   2   267.315 234.495
2   3   267.315 234.495
2   4   267.972 232.526
2   5   267.972 232.526
2   6   267.972 231.213
2   7   267.972 231.213
3   1   267.315 230.556
3   2   267.315 230.556
3   3   267.972 227.931
3   4   267.972 227.931
3   5   267.972 227.931
3   6   267.972 227.931
3   7   267.972 225.962
```

If I make a scatter plot, I get this:

```
plt.scatter(df["x [pixel]"],df["y [pixel]"])
```

[image: scatter plot]

I can extract the TID_index in a list with:

```
TID_index = df.index.get_level_values("TID").unique()
```

But when I try to use those indexes as labels, I get a unique label in the plot with the first element of the TID_index:

```
plt.scatter(df["x [pixel]"],df["y [pixel]"])
plt.legend(TID_index)
```

[image: scatter plot with label]

My goal is to have every value in TID_index as labels. If you could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand, all your points are the same (color, shape, etc.), therefore `legend()` assumes you only want one entry. What should be the points that show up next to the the other TID values in the legend box?

Comment: The dataset belongs to a tracking software. The TID is the item number and the PID is the frame number where this item appears.

Comment: My question was more about the desired output. Did you want to have points color coded by TID? Because if so, that was not clear from your question.

Comment: Sorry for not expressing myself properly. That is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `scatterplot` from [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/). The `hue` argument of the function is used to indicate a grouping variable that will produce points with different color:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(df["x [pixel]"], df["y [pixel]"],
                hue=df.index.get_level_values("TID"), legend='full')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have only 3 TID values, but I get 4 labels. I don't understand it

Comment: Sorry, my bad. This can be fixed by adding `legend=Full` to the `scatterplot` command. Without this, seaborn assumes `TID` to be a continuous variable rather than a categorical one. I updated my answer accordingly.